# What's causing my script to only say one message in response to ;cal 0 / 0 and something that isn't 0, divided by 0

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to figure this out for 20 minutes and have come to no solutions

Here is the code snippet I'll give you, it isn't the full script because I know that only this part is incorrect:

```js
                    var x = (Number((content).slice(5, 6)))
                    var y = (Number((content).slice(9, 10)))
                    if (x === 0 && y === 0) {
                        msg.reply(`Say you have 0 dogs, and you have 0 friends to let pet the dogs, then you have 0 happiness, because their are 0 dogs to cheer you up. The answer is 0.`)
                    } else if (x !== 0 && y === 0) {
                        msg.reply(`You can't divide by zero bruh.`)
                    } else {
                        msg.reply(`The quotient is ${x / y}`)
                    }
```

Update: Nevermind I figured it out, I just changed === to ==, and !== to != and it worked!

Comment: did you log the value of x  and y?

Comment: What is the value of `content`?

Comment: `content` is equal to `msg.content.toLowerCase()` and I had tried it.

Comment: It's solved now though so it doesn't matter.